# In Windows Server 2003 R2, how do you get into the Optional Component Manager to install ADAM SP1?

Tags: windows-server-2003, adam

In Windows Server 2003 R2, how do you get into the Optional Component Manager to install ADAM SP1?  I cannot find this Optional Component Manager.. is this equivalent to Add/Remove Windows Components?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should find it in the Add/Remove Windows Components --> Active Directory Services --> ADAM.

[image]
[image]

The ADAM installer itself is located on disc 2 of the Windows Server 2003 R2 install media, under the `CMPNENTS\R2\PACKAGES\ADAM\I386\ADAM` directory.

Technet has a guide titled [Step-by-Step Guide to Deploying ADAM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756986%28WS.10%29.aspx) which details requirements, install, configuration and management.